# docker toolbox Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certific ate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I'm having error when trying to pull any images from docker hub. I use docker toolbox community edition on windows 8.1

**Ex:** when trying to pull images with command: `docker pull ubuntu` I get error response like this:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

**Note:** I get the same error when trying login from docker quick terminal.

:[image: login ssh to default machine]

Comment: I think you have to update `update-ca-trust` for the registry. `curl -k https://registry-1.docker.io/ca -o /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/registry-1.docker.io.crt`

Comment: thanks. sorry do i have to ssh to vm ?

Comment: I am sharing you the steps in answer section just wait.

Answer (score 1):

If your OS is RHEL/Centos than follow this :

**Step 1:** *Login as root user*

**Step 2:** *Create a directory.*

```
   $ mkdir -p  /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
   $ cd /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
```

**Step 3:** *Download the DTR/Registry CA certificate.*

```
   $ curl -k https://registry-1.docker.io/ca -o /etc/pki/ca-
     trust/source/anchors/registry-1.docker.io.crt
   $ ls -ltr
   root@centos:/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors# ls -ltr
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2000 May  3 10:38 registry-1.docker.io.crt
   $ chmod +x /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/registry-1.docker.io.crt
```

**Step 4:** *Refresh the list of certificates to trust.*

```
     $ sudo update-ca-trust
```

**Step 5:** *Restart the Docker Daemon.*

```
     $ systemctl restart docker.service
```

**Step 6:** *Verification*

```
  $ docker login https://registry-1.docker.io/
  Username: your-user-name
  Password:
  Login Succeeded
```

Comment: is this can be applied to windows ? im try using your steps to login on docker default machine. i added screenshot provided in the question

Comment: no this will not apply on windows this is for centos/RHEL linux

Comment: can you share which os is this in screenshot ?

Comment: im using windows 8.1

Comment: it's not a verification, I can login but got the same error with pull.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me is because of the mirror source:

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "registry-mirrors": ["http://hub-mirror.c.163.com"],
  "insecure-registries":["registry-1.docker.io"]
}
```

Partial modification of Docker Engine;
And about version:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyNdN.png)